# Installing Debug version of app while Production version is installed

Tags: android

I have created an app through Eclipse and have uploaded it in the app store. I have the app installed in my phone.

Now I am working on an update. I am having trouble installing the app because it tells me the signature is different.

I know that this is due to using different keystores to sign each. But I dont want to uninstall the app 'cause I want to make sure that the app is able to go to the normal app update process.

Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions to this for you:

1. Change the package name to some thing different like com.example.myapp.debug and remove that from the package name before publishing (this would have to be in the manifest)
2. Yes you could uninstall the app, do debug work, then uninstall the debug and reinstall from app store, push the update and wait for Google Play to register that version.
3. Do as Kai said, sign the new version and install it as an update, but then you won't get the updates as triggered by Google Play unless you uninstall and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Sign your new version, then you can install it as an update as opposed to uninstalling the Google Play version. This is probably the only way.